# Visiting Pakistan with 6-month validity passport

Tags: passports, us-citizens, pakistan

I have a US passport, which is set to expire on July 9th, 2018. I'm visiting Pakistan from March 21st to April 2nd. I have a Pakistan visa, which is valid until the expiration of my passport and it has multiple entries for up to 1 year stay.

Would I be fine if my passport expires in 3 months and I'm only staying in Pakistan for 1 week? I do not plan to overstay.

Comment: If it's anything like Europe or the US they won't let you in if your passport will expire soon.

Comment: I must admit I never understood why a password has some expiration date **but** in most cases they won't accept your passport if it is "close" to it (and I have a hard time thinking of 3-6 months as "close") ...

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Pakistan page at travel.state.gov](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Pakistan.html),

> PASSPORT VALIDITY:
>
> Six months beyond the date of arrival

There don't appear to be any exceptions to this. However, I couldn't find a page on a Pakistan government site that says anything about passport requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Most countries ([including Pakistan](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Pakistan.html)) require a minimum of six months validity on your passport. Be aware that this may also apply to any countries you're transiting through (I'm assuming there's no direct flight from the US).